# Xlookup not returning symbol and color

Tags: excel, excel-formula, colors, fonts, lookup

I have a table like below

[image]

after applying xlookup formula i get like below

[image]

the formula is working good but ignore the color and symbol from the lookup columns

is there any solution for the same

Comment: Excel formulas only return values, no formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Harun is correct, `XLOOKUP` will only return values.

To get the color to populate correctly, use conditional formatting to create rules to where, if a cell contains "Delivered to Customer" it will be green, and where "In Flight" is present, yellow. Repeat with any other colors/tags.

[image]

The symbol is a bit odd but could be a custom text format. This custom format `● @` will add the dot before your text.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot actually I was using icon sets with 4 colours but custom text format was difficult in that case  , and now your input is very clear i can skip the xlookup now